# Timeseries of unique users

Tags: python, pandas

I am utilizing pandas to process some logs to provide some analytics. The logfile is essentially: **username,datetime** on an hour by hour basis

```
user1, 2021-01-01 12:00 
user2, 2021-01-02 12:00 
user1, 2021-01-01 13:00 
user1, 2021-01-01 14:00 
user1, 2021-01-01 15:00 
user3, 2021-01-01 15:00
```

What I require is a timeseries of the cumulative users. The bruteforce approach I can do is loop over the time series and add a "1" in a new column when a new user is 1st seen.

```
user1, 2021-01-01 12:00, 1
user2, 2021-01-02 12:00, 1 
user1, 2021-01-01 13:00, 0 
user1, 2021-01-01 14:00, 0 
user1, 2021-01-01 15:00, 0 
user3, 2021-01-01 15:00, 1
```

This way a cumulative sum can be generated

```
user1, 2021-01-01 12:00, 1,1
user2, 2021-01-02 12:00, 1,2 
user1, 2021-01-01 13:00, 0,2 
user1, 2021-01-01 14:00, 0,2 
user1, 2021-01-01 15:00, 0,2 
user3, 2021-01-01 15:00, 1,3
```

Is there a more elegant way of cumulating such data on an hour basis?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cumulative number of unique elements for pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685378/cumulative-number-of-unique-elements-for-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure that it's [sorted](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `datetime`.

```
df.sort_values(['datetime','user'], inplace=True)
```

2. [Cumulative sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html?highlight=cumsum) of non-[duplicate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html?highlight=duplicated#pandas.DataFrame.duplicated) users.

```
df['cumulative_users'] = (~df['user'].duplicated()).cumsum()
```

Note that by default `keep='first'` will "Mark duplicates as True except for the first occurrence", so negating (`~`) and accumulating will increment by 1 for first occurrence of the user id, 0 for subsequent.

For a complete [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.array([
    ('user1', '2021-01-01 12:00'),
    ('user2', '2021-01-02 12:00'),
    ('user1', '2021-01-01 13:00'),
    ('user1', '2021-01-01 14:00'),
    ('user1', '2021-01-01 15:00'),
    ('user3', '2021-01-01 15:00')
], dtype = [('user','U5'),('datetime',datetime)])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
df.sort_values(['datetime','user'], inplace=True)
df['cumulative_users'] = (~df['user'].duplicated()).cumsum()
print(df)
```

returns:

```
    user          datetime  cumulative_users
0  user1  2021-01-01 12:00                 1
2  user1  2021-01-01 13:00                 1
3  user1  2021-01-01 14:00                 1
4  user1  2021-01-01 15:00                 1
5  user3  2021-01-01 15:00                 2
1  user2  2021-01-02 12:00                 3
```

Comment: Great thanks, this provided the clues to adapt it.